# Symfony 2.6 "The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable."

Tags: php, symfony

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong here, or how to make it work. I've tried removing my symfony files from vendor/symfony, reinstalling them from composer install and clearing my cache many times over.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this?

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable." at /var/www/html/allTheKisses/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ExceptionHandler.php line 74 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

My config.yaml is as follows

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form:
      resources:
        - BraincraftedBootstrapBundle:Form:bootstrap.html.twig

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ GarethIndexBundle, GarethpPhotosBundle  ]
    node: /usr/bin/node
    node_paths: [/usr/lib/node_modules]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less: ~
#            apply_to: "\.less$"
#        lessphp:
#            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php
#            apply_to: "\.less$"
        uglifycss:
            bin: /usr/bin/uglifycss
        uglifyjs2:
          bin: /usr/bin/uglifyjs
          apply_to:   "\.js"
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

braincrafted_bootstrap:
    less_filter: less

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

gregwar_image:
    throw_exception: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced with analogous problem.

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable." at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1806 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable. at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php:1806)"} []
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable." at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1806 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable. at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php:1806)"} []
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable." at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1806 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable. at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php:1806)"} []
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable." at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1806 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable. at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php:1806)"} []
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable." at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1806 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable. at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php:1806)"} []
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable." at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1806 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): The exception handler must be a valid PHP callable. at .../app/cache/prod/classes.php:1806)"} []
```

It happened after I made `php composer update` on my local machine and transfer only `src/` and `vendor/` dirs to the production server. After uploading `app/bootstrap.cache.php` the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but somewhere you call `Debug::enable();`. This invokes the ExceptionHandler and the ExceptionHandler::handle is callable so I don't know what your setup does.

Try to find this `Debug::enable();` line and comment it out, to see if the error is gone. 
For example what is

```
gregwar_image:
  throw_exception: true
```

Is there maybe a Gregwar ExceptionHandler extending it and the `handle` method of it is not callable?

Comment: Thanks for your post, but after doing a grep, the only place it was being called was in app_dev.php, and this error was appearing on live anyway. After this an many other errors, I just ended up making a new project and copying over all of my bundles and configs and stuff